# Capture actual SQL statement running as part of Dynamic Sql in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2017. It has SP which inserts data into table passed via parameters.

```
create table employee(
id int,
first_name varchar(100),
last_name varchar(100),
salary int,
city varchar(100)
)

Create PROCEDURE MasterInsertUpdateDelete  
(  
@id INTEGER,  
@first_name VARCHAR(10),  
@last_name VARCHAR(10),  
@salary INTEGER,  
@city VARCHAR(20),  
@StatementType nvarchar(20) = ''  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    IF @StatementType = 'Insert'  
    BEGIN  
        insert into employee (id,first_name,last_name,salary,city) values( @id, @first_name, @last_name, @salary, @city)  
    END  
    IF @StatementType = 'Select'  
    BEGIN  
        select * from employee  
    END
END
```

Suppose I execute SP using below statement

```
exec MasterInsertUpdateDelete
@id = 1,  
@first_name = 'Vijay',  
@last_name = 'Kumar',  
@salary = 100,  
@city = 'Pune',  
@StatementType = 'Insert'
```

Now I want to capture original query (replace with parameter values) which is being executed on DB server 
i.e. ***insert into employee (id,first_name,last_name,salary,city) values( 1, 'Vijay', 'Kumar', 100, 'Test')***

I used SQL profiler and exended events but it gives me SQL statement along with parameters
i.e. 
***insert into employee (id,first_name,last_name,salary,city) values( @id, @first_name, @last_name, @salary, @city)***

Practically I have more complex store procedure as Dynamic SQL. I would like to capture the executing statement with replace variable values. How can we achieve it in MS SQL Server?

Comment: The query being run *is* `insert into employee (id,first_name,last_name,salary,city) values( @id, @first_name, @last_name, @salary, @city)`. The statement you have is *not* a dynamic statement, it's a **parametrised** statement. The 2 are very different.

Comment: A dynamic statement would look something like `DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX); SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' WHERE MyColumn = @MyParam;'; EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@MyParam nvarchar(10)', @MyParam;`

Comment: Maybe you want to show the [OUTPUT INSERTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?#a-using-output-into-with-a-simple-insert-statement)?

Comment: But it can be a multiple query executions. I mean in the example I have used simple insert statement but it can be complex SQL select statement as part of dynamic SQL.

Comment: Having had cause to look into this myself in the past, I'm fairly certain this is simply not possible to do in an automated fashion. The best you can do is capture the `RPC:Starting` event (which captures the parameters of the sproc) and the `SP:StmtStarting` events (which capture the individual statements, parameterized). These together will allow you to deduce the parameter values actually in use. There are no separate events/fields to capture ambient variable/parameter values. Capturing full execution plans also gives you parameter values, but that's very expensive.

Comment: @Larnu In case of sp_executesql, it gives me original sql stmt in the event sp:stmtstarting/sp:stmtcompleted. But if I created new variable from existing parameter then normal sql statement show that variables as it is in the trace SQL statement. Can we trace executing SQL statement for variable value instead of variable name?

Comment: You would need to capture the `EXEC` statement to find the values of those parameters, @NitinK .

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert Yes It looks like there is no mechanism to capture query with variable value instead of variable name